Input loses focus after typing a character
I'm using primeng table.Each table has its own columns.
Example of a table:
annexOneTable: any[] = [
        { name: 'N0.', field: 'declarationOrder', width: '2rem' },
      //other fields
    ];
 isDateField(value: any, fieldName: string): boolean {
  //return true when date otherwise false
    }


    isNumberField(value: any, fieldName: string): boolean {
        //return true when numberotherwise false

    }
    
    trackRecord(index: number, record: any) {
        return record.id;
    }

 formatValue(value: any, fieldName: string): string {
      //return the wanted format as string for specific fields 
    }


<p-table
                    [value]="declarationList"
                    styleClass="p-datatable-gridlines"
                    [tableStyle]="{ 'min-width': '50rem' }"
                    [columns]="[tableColumns]"  //which is dynamic 
                    #dt2
                    [rowTrackBy]="trackRecord"
                >
                    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
                        <tr>
                            <ng-container *ngFor="let col of tableColumns">
                                <th [style.width]="col.width">
                                    {{ t(col.name) }}
                                </th>
                            </ng-container>
                        </tr>
                    </ng-template>
                    <ng-template
                        pTemplate="body"
                        let-line
                        let-rowIndex="rowIndex"
                    >
                        <tr>
                            <ng-container *ngFor="let col of tableColumns">
                                <td
                                    [style.width]="col.width"
                                    [pEditableColumn]="col.field"
                                >
                                    <ng-container
                                        *ngIf="
                                            isNumberField(
                                                line[col.field],
                                                col.field
                                            );
                                            else nonEditable
                                        "
                                    >
                                        <p-cellEditor>
                                            <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                                                <ng-container
                                                    *ngIf="
                                                        isDateField(
                                                            line[col.field],
                                                            col.field
                                                        );
                                                        else textInput
                                                    "
                                                >
                                                    <p-calendar
                                                        [(ngModel)]="
                                                            line[col.field]
                                                        "
                                                        dateFormat="yy-mm-dd"
                                                        class="p-inputtext-sm"
                                                        style="width: 100%"
                                                    ></p-calendar>
                                                </ng-container>
                                                <ng-template #textInput>
                                                    <input
                                                        pInputText
                                                        [(ngModel)]="
                                                            line[col.field]
                                                        "
                                                        class="p-inputtext-sm"
                                                        pKeyFilter="num"
                                                        [style.font-size]="
                                                            '0.75rem'
                                                        "
                                                        [style.font-weight]="
                                                            '500'
                                                        "
                                                        style="float: right"
                                                    />
                                                </ng-template>
                                            </ng-template>
                                            <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                                                <span
                                                    [ngStyle]="{
                                                        'font-size': '0.75rem',
                                                        'font-weight': '500',
                                                        float: isNumeric(
                                                            line[col.field]
                                                        )
                                                            ? 'right'
                                                            : 'none'
                                                    }"
                                                >
                                                    {{
                                                        formatValue(
                                                            line[col.field],
                                                            col.field
                                                        )
                                                    }}
                                                </span>
                                            </ng-template>
                                        </p-cellEditor>
                                    </ng-container>
                                    <ng-template #nonEditable>
                                        <span
                                            [ngStyle]="{
                                                'font-size': '0.75rem',
                                                'font-weight': '500',
                                                float: isNumeric(
                                                    line[col.field]
                                                )
                                                    ? 'right'
                                                    : 'none'
                                            }"
                                        >
                                            {{
                                                formatValue(
                                                    line[col.field],
                                                    col.field
                                                )
                                            }}
                                        </span>
                                    </ng-template>
                                </td>
                            </ng-container>
                        </tr>
                    </ng-template>
                </p-table>

Every thing works fine until I select a cell of type number to edit, when typing any symbol I lose focus on input and that input can't be focused again.
No errors in console and after searching I expect problem will be solved by trackBy. But it didn't work for me.

Could you please bring your game to stackblitz?

I add a property to my array annexOneTable wich is isEditable of type boolean.
 { name: 'N0.', field: 'declarationOrder', width: '2rem',editable:true }//the added property is editable

And i change the condition in the ng-container that was making the unexpected behaviour.
 <ng-container *ngIf="(col.isEditable);else nonEditable">REST OF MY CODE</ng-container>

And it worked for me.

I imagine that the problem is that, when you change a cell, Angular "try to repaint" all the table (sorry I have no time to check and create a stackblitz with a p-table).
You can use track by in your *ngFor or iterate over a diferent variable
  <ng-container *ngFor="let col of tableColumns;trackBy:trackByIndex">


  trackByIndex(index: number, item: any): number {
    return index;
  }

Really you can track by some particular property of the column, I choose a "universal" track

trackByIndex should be applied on declarationList.

trackRecord by index works fine now.i tried to console the index and i saw it in my console.But the problem persist.Any other suggestions ?

I want to say the *ngFor related to tableColumns in your .html, not the indicate in the [rowTrackBy]

I found the problem was here.
*ngIf="isNumberField(line[col.field],col.field);else nonEditable"
So when i remove it the problem disappear.
I ll try to make changes to avoid that problem.
